# Different server request behaviour within web workers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

Within our web application we are using the following method of server communication

- XMLHttpRequest

We are sending the same content/data in both cases but the XMLHttpRequest is ran inside a webwork.

The browser that is been used is chrome with --disable-web-security flag.

Is there any reason why a web worker XMLHttpRequest would fail inside the worker but not outside?

If the exact same code for the XMLHttpRequest is moved from the worker to normal JavaScript it works perfect?

ERROR:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Could you give us the actual error message you're getting?  And code would be nice too.

Comment: are you trying to access cross domain data?

Comment: Are you using the same code inside and outside the WebWorker? Where are you using the jQuery wrapper, does that change anything?

Comment: Same code inside and outisde the worker but inside the worker it causes a cross domian error and outside it works fine, could it be becuse the script is a new javascript thread that it doesnt run under the "disable-web-security" flag?

Comment: The error says it all: Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. You can't decently XHR from a file:// location. Open the page via a server (localhost is fine, but it has to be served by a web server).

Comment: Well yes/no depends what you mean, the process is like this   create webworker >> call function >> function does xml request to server( this is where it fails) >> web works terminates           but if i do the same without the worker it works fine, its definatly not server side thats the issue thats been tested.. sorry for any cunfusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

After a lot of effort from most of the team here what we have discovered is that in Chrome, web workers appear to run with different security over that of the main browser. (by this I mean when the browser runs with --disable-web-security the web worker doesn't).

We were trying to access a domain resource (http://domain.com/resource) from (file:///). Despite the browser running with web security disable, the resolution was to have the server respond with a header of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'.

Although we could have used file:/// instead of the wildcard we can't be sure of how this might change across devices in production, and as we are running in a closed network this is less of a concern.

The code at the end of the day remains completely unchanged and only this change in the headers of the server resonse was needed.

Comment: Just hit the same issue, posted a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=254993.  Feel free to star it if you want to be notified of updates.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues that could be causing this.  Which one is the culprit depends on your setup.

**1. You're trying to access a file from a web app**

It sounds like this might be the issue you're referring to.  Chrome has a pretty strict access control policy that says you can't access local files remotely.  No way around it sadly.

**2. You're trying to access a file from another file and haven't enabled it**

The only exception to the access control regulations about local files is when you're making the request from another local file.  This is still disabled to default and needs to be enabled by passing the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag when you start chrome.

Comment: Does --disable-web-security flag not --allow-file-access-from-files aswell?

Comment: Not sure. So you are accessing this from another file then?

Comment: Well yes/no depends what you mean, the process is like this   create webworker >> call function >> function does xml request to server( this is where it fails) >> web works terminates           but if i do the same without the worker it works fine, its definatly not server side thats the issue thats been tested.. sorry for any cunfusion